# Push different objects of view controller of same class in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am creating two different object of a single `UIViewController`. One for list and 2nd for detail information. I am using one `UIViewController` for both those. Now when I push the 1st object and when user tap for detail I again create a object of that same `UIViewController` and push it in `UINavigationController`. 
So I want to know: does we can do so because my `UINavigationController` is making delegate calls back with the objects. A delegate call back that should call the method on 1st instance is  calling the method on 2nd instance.

---

**i think its possible. i found the mistake in the code.**

Comment: UIViewController instances aren't cached (actually, very few classes actually are cached).  Instances are unique entities when initialized manually.

Comment: IF you say *i think its possible. i found the mistake in the code.* then you should consider deleting the post.

Comment: actually i had left this question because it might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push the same `UIViewcontroller` again in `UINavigationController` stack. There is no issues with that.
`UINavigationController` make an stack of `ViewControllers` so you can add as many objects as you require whether they are instances of same `UIViewController` Class or not. Because all instances are added explicitly.

Hope it helps you.